# Помогите с пунктуацией в данном тексте.

Tags: пунктуация

Никто не знает, когда именно качество тормозов транспортного средства сыграет свою роль: будь то зазевавшийся пешеход, переходящий дорогу, ребенок, выскочивший на проезжую часть за своим мячом или какой-нибудь автомобиль, водитель которого не справился с управлением. Можно с уверенностью сказать, что среди всех деталей и узлов автомобиля, тормозная система является одной из самых важных. Своевременная замена колодок превентивная мера, позволяющая повысить безопасность дорожного движения.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Никто не знает, **в какой именно ситуации** качество тормозов транспортного средства сыграет свою роль: **будет ли это** зазевавшийся пешеход, переходящий дорогу, ребенок, выскочивший на проезжую часть за своим мячом, или какой-нибудь автомобиль, водитель которого не справился с управлением. **Но** можно с уверенностью сказать, что среди всех деталей и узлов автомобиля тормозная система является одной из самых важных. Своевременная замена колодок - превентивная мера, позволяющая повысить безопасность дорожного движения.

**Примечание**

В текст внесены небольшие стилистические поправки.

Выражение "будь то"  используется примерно в таких случаях: В любой ситуации, будь то зазевавшийся пешеход, переходящий дорогу, ребенок, выскочивший на проезжую часть за своим мячом или какой-нибудь автомобиль, водитель которого не справился с управлением, очень важно качество тормозов.

Пример:  И формы собственности, будь то частная или общественная, должны иметь одни правила игры на территории города.

Comment: *Но можно с уверенностью сказать, что среди всех деталей и узлов автомобиля, тормозная система является одной из самых важных.* Вроде вторая запятая совершенно лишняя.

Comment: Спасибо, лишняя, конечно.